# Pom.xml project build error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I have imported maven projects in my eclipse, but I am getting the following error in pom.xml-

> Project build error:
>   'dependencyManagement.dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for
>   jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is
>   ${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar

I am kind of new to maven, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add an environment variable JAVA_HOME

Comment: Where should I add this environment variable?

Comment: Go to advance system settings (Windows) , there youwill find all the environment variables. Add JAVA_HOME with the value as path to your JDK

Comment: I already have JAVA_HOME set up there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've specified a dependency on `jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar` with a `<systemPath>` of `${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar`. `${JAVA_HOME}` is not a valid [Maven property](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html). The syntax to read the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is `${env.JAVA_HOME}`. However, the same information is exposed as a [system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) named `java.home`, so `${java.home}` is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a lack of Maven property —— `JAVA_HOME` . You can add it to your pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <!--  your java home  -->
        <JAVA_HOME>/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_202</JAVA_HOME>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sam Hanes' answer is great. However, there are two points:

1. ${java.home} represents the installation directory for **JRE**, which is sometimes different from the installation directory for **JDK**. And the tools.jar is usually at `"INSTALLATION_DIRECOTRY_OF_JDK"/lib/tools.jar`
2. If you use `${env.JAVA_HOME}` and you are in linux, be sure that you have correctly exported `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. You can use `export` command in bash to see whether there is a line like `declare -x JAVA_HOME=....`. In particular, you should write your .bash_profile or .bash_rc like:

```
    export JAVA_HOME=THE_DIRECOTRY_OF_YOU_JDK
    export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

instead of

```
    JAVA_HOME=THE_DIRECOTRY_OF_YOU_JDK
    PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

If you miss `export` in your .bash_profile or .bash_rc, you can still use `$JAVA_HOME` in your bash terminal. However, Maven cannot recognize what `env.JAVA_HOME` means.

Answer (score -4):

Look for `tools.jar` which should be in `jdk/lib`, if not mean download latest jdk or add `tools.jar` to this location. This should fix the issue.